# Trying to get recaptcha token of a site gives error

Tags: javascript, debugging, reverse-engineering, captcha

This code is in the website

```js
 $('#main-content').submit(function (event) {
        var sk = "6Le7HZQeAAAAANyVJZBpFKiWwDstptVGJ2aGbyMC";
        event.preventDefault();

        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute(sk, {action: "vote"}).then(function (token) {
                $("#main-content").prepend('<input type="hidden" name="sitekey" value="' + sk + '">');
                $("#main-content").prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="vote">');
                $("#main-content").prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
                $("#main-content").unbind('submit').submit();
            });
        });
    });
```

I tried doing this in the console when on the site
[image]

But it gave me an error, I am stuck and I do not know if I can debug it

I also tried copying and pasting the script that the site had
[image]
But there was no change in the form

Comment: Invalid site key, is pretty obvious. Did YOU put the site key in the right place?

Comment: Yes I did , the code sent is just above the screenshot

Comment: It does not look like any of this: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: Is it YOUR key or are you copying code from another site?

Comment: Read this
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge

This is the site that has this code and am trying to get token prior to submitting the code `view-source:https://best-minecraft-servers.co/server-pikanetwork.4401/vote` Line 401-413

Comment: No, it isn't mine. The site key am trying to make a script for the site so I need the token prior to submitting the form

Comment: You need your OWN key. the key belongs to one captcha and cannot be used somewhere else. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#recently-my-recaptcha-widget-started-displaying-invalid-site-key.-whats-happening

Comment: So there is no way to get the captcha token prior to sending the form?

Comment: follow the instructions at google's site. They even have a link to [Stackoverflow recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) questions. It is unclear if you get an error because you are trying to reuse someone elses key or because your script is wrong